# Convert array with two types to HashMap, TreeMap, LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, arrays, object, converters, typeconverter

Create arrays:

{int, String}, {String, String}, {int, long}, {String,boolean}, {String, double}, {int, class Car}, {String, class Car}

Convert into HashMap, TreeMap, LinkedHashMap

This is class Car:

```
public class Car implements Comparable{

    int id;
    String car_name;
    String number;

    public Car(int id, String car_name, String number) {
        this.id = id;
        this.car_name = car_name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", car_name='" + car_name + '\'' +
                ", number='" + number + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

There is my code:

```
public class Main {

    private static HashMap<Integer,String> toHM(Object[][] a){
        HashMap<Integer,String> h = new HashMap<>();

        for (Object[] o : a){
            h.put((Integer) o[0], (String) o[1]);
        }
        return h;
    }

    private static HashMap<Integer,String> toLHM(Object[][] a){
        HashMap<Integer,String> h = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (Object[] o : a){
            h.put((Integer) o[0], (String) o[1]);
        }
        return h;
    }

    private static TreeMap<Integer,String> toTM(Object[][] a){
        TreeMap<Integer,String> h = new TreeMap<>();

        for (Object[] o : a){
            h.put((Integer) o[0], (String) o[1]);
        }
        return h;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object[][] a = new Object[2][2];
        a[0][0] = 1;
        a[0][1] = "test";
        a[1][0] = 2;
        a[1][1] = "other test";

       HashMap<Integer,String> aHM = toHM(a);
       HashMap<Integer,String> aLHH = toLHM(a);
       TreeMap<Integer,String> aTM = toTM(a);

    }
}
```

This is code correct ? May, it is better to have to use generics in that code?
Do I understand how to solve this problem ?

Comment: You cannot just cast Objects to String or Integer.  Rather override your methods to take different arrays or have an instanceof if statements in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <S, T1, T2> S convert(Object[] inputobject, Class<S> mapType,
        Class<T1> keyType, Class<T2> valueType)
        throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    Map<T1, T2> map = (Map<T1, T2>) mapType.newInstance();
    map.put((T1) inputobject[0], (T2) inputobject[1]);
    return (S) map;
}
```

- **inputObject**: the Object array
- **mapType** : Class of map for eg. Hashmap, Treemap etc
- **keyType** : Class of Key eg. String, Integer etc.
- **valueType**: Class of value

Sample Input:

```
Object[] obj = new Object[] { 1, "test" };
System.out.println(convert(obj, HashMap.class, Integer.class, String.class));
```

Sample Output:

```
{1=test}
```

I hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

1. As per the standard, you should always code to an interface. I mean the reference should be an interface and object should be the implementation.
2. As I see you have the same body in all the three methods, cant I have a single method which returns a map. You can add a parameter and make assign the same to the reference.
3. he invoking function can captue the desired return type.

Below is an pseudo code for your assistance

eg.

Invoking function :

```
HashMap hMap = getMap(Object[][] a, HashMap.class);
```

Method signature :

```
private <R> R (Object[][] a,Class<R> responseClazz){
    Map mp = new responseClazz();
    .....
    return mp;
}
```